# How to do nesting manufacturers like site.com/brands/BrandName/productName in OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I need to do nesting links like *site.com/brands/brandName/productName*. Now it's like *site.com/brandName/productName*.

I've tried **.htaccess** and add '*/brands'* in **seo_url.php** and it's doesn't work. In seo url option of a brand, I've added '*brands/bmw'* and received **404**.
Should I rewrite a controller or **seo_url.php** differently?

**OpenCart v3.0.2.0**

```
<?php
class ControllerStartupSeoUrl extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            // remove any empty arrays from trailing
            if (utf8_strlen(end($parts)) == 0) {
                array_pop($parts);
            }

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($query->row['query'] && $url[0] != 'information_id' && $url[0] != 'manufacturer_id' && $url[0] != 'category_id' && $url[0] != 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
                }
        }
    }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

        $url = '';

        $data = array();

        parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($data['route'])) {
                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
                } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                    $categories = explode('_', $value);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                        } else {
                            $url = '';

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    unset($data[$key]);

                } 
            }
        }

        if ($url) {
            unset($data['route']);

            $query = '';

            if ($data) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $query .= '&' . rawurlencode((string)$key) . '=' . rawurlencode((is_array($value) ? http_build_query($value) : (string)$value));
                }

                if ($query) {
                    $query = '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', trim($query, '&'));
                }
            }

            return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code try this:

```php
<?php
class ControllerStartupSeoUrl extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Add rewrite to url class
        if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
            $this->url->addRewrite($this);
        }

        // Decode URL
        if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
            $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

            // remove any empty arrays from trailing
            if (utf8_strlen(end($parts)) == 0) {
                array_pop($parts);
            }

            foreach ($parts as $part) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                    if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                        if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                            $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                        } else {
                            $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                        }
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                        $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                        $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                    }

                    if ($query->row['query'] && $url[0] != 'information_id' && $url[0] != 'manufacturer_id' && $url[0] != 'category_id' && $url[0] != 'product_id') {
                        $this->request->get['route'] = $query->row['query'];
                    }
                } elseif ($part == 'brand') {
                    // don't send the user to 'not found page'
                } else {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
                } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
                    $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
                }
        }
    }
    }

    public function rewrite($link) {
        $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

        $url = '';

        $data = array();

        parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($data['route'])) {
                if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                        //add brands to the url
                        if ($key == 'manufacturer_id') {
                            $url .= '/brand';
                        }
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                        unset($data[$key]);
                    }
                } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                    $categories = explode('_', $value);

                    foreach ($categories as $category) {
                        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

                        if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
                            $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                        } else {
                            $url = '';

                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    unset($data[$key]);

                } 
            }
        }

        if ($url) {
            unset($data['route']);

            $query = '';

            if ($data) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $query .= '&' . rawurlencode((string)$key) . '=' . rawurlencode((is_array($value) ? http_build_query($value) : (string)$value));
                }

                if ($query) {
                    $query = '?' . str_replace('&', '&amp;', trim($query, '&'));
                }
            }

            return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
        } else {
            return $link;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now url is correct (brands/brandName) but I've received the same manufacturers page with all brands.

Comment: brand not brands. brands is already taken and is in your oc_url_alias table. so you can't use brands or you can play with the if statement and try to catch brands before it validates the alias table.

Comment: brands is example, i need url like site.com/katalog/bmw(brandname)/productName. Now it's site.com/bmw/productname

Comment: every case requires a custom setup. in method index your write the rules fro 'reading' the urls. in method rewrite your define the rules for 'writing' the urls. you can follow my example and extend it to any patter you wish. for example if you want to add katalog in the begining, you need to add to the rewrite method a case where you add $url .= '/katalog'; and then you need to catch that logic in the index function to properly forward the user and not to an not_found page.